# Does not exist activity class file - why?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I dont know what is this error:

> 05/19 15:21:12: Launching 'app' on LGE (My phone).
>
> $ adb shell am start -n
>   "com.cukorders.helping/com.cukorders.helping.ChatActivity" -a
>   android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Error
>   while executing: am start -n
>   "com.cukorders.helping/com.cukorders.helping.ChatActivity" -a
>   android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=com.cukorders.helping/.ChatActivity } Error type 3 Error: Activity
>   class {com.cukorders.helping/com.cukorders.helping.ChatActivity} does
>   not exist.
>
> Error while Launching activity

but ChatActivity does exist that named ChatActivity.java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcLiZ.png)

Comment: You should define your activity in the Manifest file.

Comment: Can you share the code from where this error originates from?

Comment: File->Invalidate caches/Restart

Comment: This error  originates from "Run"

Comment: Check that your Activity is in the right package: com.cukorders.helping.ChatActivity

Answer (score 0):

Your activities need to be defined in the manifest file. The startup activity should be defined like this:

```
<activity android:name=".put your started activity name here"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: <activity android:name=".ChatActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: sry but i could't understand. could u check captured image in my post?

Comment: Try with the fully qualified name like "com.your.path.ChatActivity"

Comment: I understand and edit to <activity android:name="com.cukorders.helping.ChatActivity"> but error does not changed.

Comment: I was hoping you could check my full code. My coding skills are so poor that it's so difficult. Could you tell me your e-mail address if u don't mind?

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be because of **Refactoring**, if you have done it.
It may be resolved like this:
Click on **Files>Invalidate Caches/Restart**
[1] Clean your project file.
[2] Delete your Build directory.
[3] Restart your IDE(Android Studio).
[4] Rebuild your project and Run it.